# Convert T to &mut T with `.`?

Tags: rust

According to my understanding, next needs a `&mut Test`, but `create_test()` returns a `Test`.

Why can this be compiled?

My guess is that `.` will implicitly convert `Test` to `&mut Test`, I am not sure. Can somebody explain more about this?

```rs
pub struct Test {
    t: u64,
}

fn create_test() -> Test {
    Test {
        t: 1
    }
} 

impl Test {
    pub fn next(&mut self) {
        self.t = 10;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut t = Test { t: 20 };
    t.next();

    create_test().next();  // here
}
```

Comment: Until it's assigned to a non-`mut` variable it's considered mutable. The type only really gets locked down when you store it somewhere.

Comment: Indeed, `.` will coerce `T` into `&T` or `&mut T` as needed. This is special behavior of `.`. A manual method call `Test::next(t);` does not do this and requires an explicit `&mut t`.

Comment: When calling `.` on something the action taken depends entirely on the function itself. Some take `self`, some `&self`, `&mut self` or what have you, where the compiler determines how to handle that. In other cases it has to be `Deref` first. This is only possible if there's no limitations, as in stored in a non-`mut` variable, which would then generate an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained in the [Method-call expressions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/method-call-expr.html) section of the book.

> When looking up a method call, the receiver may be automatically dereferenced or borrowed in order to call a method.

This is exactly what is happening here. The rust compiler is automatically borrowing value returned `create_test`.